# Why doesn't $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_2$ hold in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math, theories-of-arithmetic

For a formula $\varphi(i,u)$ of arithmetic, the *bounding principle for $\varphi$* is the statement

$$\forall m \, \Big( \big( \forall i<m\ \exists u\ \varphi(i,u) \big) \to \big( \exists v\ \forall i<m\ \exists u<v\ \varphi(i,u) \big) \Big)$$

$\mathsf{B}\Sigma_n$ is the axiom schema asserting the bounding principle for every $\Sigma_n$ statement.

I understand that $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_n$ (and the induction principles   $\mathsf{I}\Sigma_n$) hold in every $\omega$-model of second order arithmetic. However, they are not theorems of $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ for $n > 2$, so there must be nonstandard models in which they fail.

My intuition for nonstandard models of arithmetic is that they look like $\mathbb{N} + \mathbb{Z} \cdot\! K$ for some linear order $K$. Thus, I am struggling to understand why $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_2$ could fail in such a model. It seems to me that for each $i<m$, you could take a witness $u_i$, and then choose $v = \max \{ u_i \}+1$ - hence $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_2$ holds. I can't see why this argument would fail in a system such as $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ which proves basic properties of computable functions.

So, I'd like to see a nonstandard model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathsf{RCA}_0 + \lnot \mathsf{B}\Sigma_2$, and a proof that $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_2$ fails in $\mathcal{M}$. I would also like any information on:

- where bounding principles are used in practice - so I can know when I am implicitly assuming $\mathsf{B}\Sigma_n$.
- references to learn more about nonstandard models in reverse mathematics.

Thanks!

Comment: In a nonstandard model the element $m$ could be nonstandard, and so there are infinitely many elements below it. Why should the maximum then exist?

Comment: @Wojowu: good point.